# Photos in server for all android full screen

Tags: android, screen-resolution, android-image, android-screen-support, imagedownload

I want to upload photos on my server so the android user can download them and see them in his device. The problem is in which [resolution](/questions/tagged/resolution) do I have to upload them in order to be shown well on every android device screen except x-large screens. I don't want to upload them in different resolutions because it won't be fair to charge the user depending on his screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Just upload a standard sized high res image and scale down if you encounter a low end device while displaying.

For example, you can upload 3 MP (2048 x 1536) images which should do well for most devices. If the device is low end, you can scale it down after checking the devices resolution.

In most cases, you don't need to worry about this. The device's gallery app will handle this for you if you just open the downloaded image (which is 3 MP) in the default gallery app via an intent.

If you are building your own display mechanism then you'll have to handle the scaling yourself.

Comment: actually I want to show them in a full screen activity inside my app. I don't store them in my device in order to show them from my gallery. Also storing uploading show big pictures will cause a very slow download and will spend many mbs if the users uses the 3g. That's why I want the most appropriate resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Loading images greater in size reduce performance .Use normal size images atmost size 1 mb.